# How to iterate rows in Pandas DataFrame Python and convert each row to String?

Tags: python

I need to iterate each rows in Dataframe and using regex check if any row contains "CHG00" pattern.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. KIndly go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not the proper way of asking question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex Method**

```
import re
def is_valid(x):
    regexp = re.compile(r'CHG00')
    return regexp.search(x) is not None
df['new_col'] = df['col1'].apply(is_valid)
```

**Pandas Method**

```
df['new_col'] = df['col1'].str.contains('CHG00')
```

Output will be a Series of boolean values, `True` being the string contains the pattern